How to show index number in renderItem for each item, maintaining previous next buttons of pagination
How can I show the index number in each flat list item, so that I can make it accurate if I go back and forth with the previous next buttons of pagination?
I have added an index prop in renderItem method to achieve the same, but it works for 3 pages, I want to create a single-line or short logic for the same.
I am showing 20 items on each page with pagination, thus adding 20 on each page.
 let updatedindex = index + 1;
      <Item
            item={item}
            index={pageNo == '1' ? updatedindex : pageNo == '2' ? 20 + updatedindex : 40 + updatedindex}
            onPress={() => { }}
            isCompleted={completedItems.includes(item._id)}
            backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
            textColor={color}
          />
    

Everything else is working fine, I only want to include the indexing with my list like 1,2,3 for each item. Here is my code for the next and previous buttons for pagination.
  const paginationNext = () => {
    if (currentPage * limit < parseInt(total)) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
      setHidePrev(true);

      let reqData = {
        Id: sId,
        pageSize: 20,
        pageNo: currentPage + 1,
      };
      getListingDataPagination(reqData);
    }
  };

  const paginationPrevious = () => {
    if (currentPage * limit < parseInt(total)) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
      let reqData = {
        Id: sId,
        pageSize: 20,
        pageNo: currentPage - 1,
      };

      getListingDataPagination(reqData);
    }
  };


Can you explain by sharing some UI what you want?

When you write out the pages and the page bounds, you observe a pattern in the minimum and maximum bounds of the pages using mathematical induction.



page number
page bounds




1
[1, 20] = [20 * 0, 20 * 0 + 20]


2
[21, 40] = [20 * 1, 20 * 1 + 20]


3
[41, 60] = [20 * 2, 20 * 2 + 20]


4
[61, 80] = [20 * 3, 20 * 3 + 20]


5
[81, 100] = [20 * 4, 20 * 4 + 20]


6
[101, 120] = [20 * 5, 20 * 5 + 20]



From the table, given a page size S and page number N, the bounds for the page can be expressed as:



minbound
maxbound




S * (N - 1)
S * (N -1) + S



As a result of this generalization, you can implement a function that returns the index for a page given the item index and the page size.


const PAGE_SIZE = 20;

function getIndexOfPageItem(idx, pageno) {
  // pre-condition: provided index must be zero-based index and less than page size
  if (idx < 0 || idx > PAGE_SIZE - 1) {
    console.error(`index should be between range of 0 and ${PAGE_SIZE}`);
    return;
  }
  const minBound = PAGE_SIZE * (pageno - 1);
  const indexOfPageItem = minBound + (idx + 1);
  const maxBound = minBound + PAGE_SIZE;

  // post-condition: computed page index must be within range of page bounds.
  if (indexOfPageItem < minBound || indexOfPageItem > maxBound) {
    console.error(`index of page item is out of bounds, minBound=${minBound},maxBound=${maxBound},indexOfPageItem=${indexOfPageItem}`);
    return;
  }
  return indexOfPageItem;
}

function test(idx, pageno, expectedPageno) {
  console.assert(
    getIndexOfPageItem(idx, pageno),
    expectedPageno,
    `Expected pageno is ${expectedPageno} when item idx=${idx} and pageno=${pageno}`);
}

test(0, 1, 1);
test(19, 1, 20);
test(0, 2, 21);
test(19, 2, 40);
test(0, 3, 41);
test(19, 3, 60);
test(0, 4, 61);
test(19, 4, 80);
test(0, 5, 81);
test(19, 5, 100);
test(0, 6, 101);
test(19, 6, 120);




Thanks for your comment @oluwafemi-sule, let me check and I'll mark it acceptable if I got my answer.

What is idx here?

idx is the item index. i.e.<Item item={item} index={getIndexOfPageItem(index, parseInt(pageNo))} ...

Wonderfully executed @oluwafemi-sule Thanks
